# powershell - close a program with an auto response

Tags: powershell, outlook

im trying to close a program (Outlook in this case) 
with an auto response when a message pops up asking if you want to clear deleted items.
*note: not all users will have that message, it depends on the profile settings.
example code:

```
Get-Process outlook | % { $_.CloseMainWindow() }
```

Now, depending on the profile's settings i can get a popup message asking me 
*"Are you sure you want to permanently delete all the items and subfolders in the "deleted items folder?"*

i want it to automaticly send a "No" as an answer.
is it doable?
thanks in advance.

Comment: What? You should include more info and maybe even pictures. I have no idea what you're talking about. Does `$_.CloseMainWindow()` trigger clearing the deleted items folder (very unlikely)?.. Not a good start for a new member. You should make your question clearer before someone closes it.

Comment: if you're such an old member you should know that new members can't post images. anyway theres an option of outlook to delete all mails in deleted items folder. and you get prompt upon exit.

Comment: But you can post links, and you can make a more detailed question so I wouldn't have to ask questions. As for you question, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and remove the EmptyTrash dword value located under `HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\<OfficeVersion>\Outlook\Preferences` before calling CloseMainWindow() (or set it to 0) and once outlook is closed set the value back to 1.

That said, there might be other prompts that will prevent Outlook from closing cleanly, such as open unsaved items and your only option would be to brutally kill the process.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [Windows Automation Snapin for PowerShell](http://wasp.codeplex.com/) which is a snapin/module that could help you interact with GUI applications.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I'm not looking for an automation that interact with the GUI. I want to close the app "gracefully" and if I get prompt to bypass it or even answer Yes/No if possible as I know in advance what the kind of a prompt message I could get. I'm starting to think I need to work with a com object or something to close outlook and maybe there's a proper switch for various outlook prompt messages that pop up upon exit. I know I can just kill the process but like I said.. "gracefully" is where I'm heading :)

Comment: The idea was that you could try to close it using your current command, and use the snapin to look for the popup, and if it appeared, click yes or no, so outlook would continue to close gracfully.